Windows Multiple IPv6 Gateways
Why does it show me multiple IPv6 GW's in my Windows 2016 Standard Server

We are facing some issues with IPv6, and was wondering if this is wrong. I do understand we cannot carry multiple gateways on a single NIC. On this NIC ipv6 is selected but is not set, only ipv4 is set and selected


I do understand we cannot carry multiple gateways on a single NIC.

You can, at least in IPv6. (Not that IPv4 has any fundamental limits against it either – just lack of specification, whereas in IPv6 the behavior somewhat more explicitly part of the spec. But for example Linux has generic support for ECMP and could easily load-balance between two IPv4 gateways as well.)
Of course it's expected that both gateways would let you reach the same destinations, etc. In theory the IPv6 specification even allows a host to have gateways from different ISPs on the same interface (and automatically choosing the correct gateway depending on source IP address) but this is not as well-supported in practice.
Either way the gateways are probably unused on your system as you don't have any IPv6 address on this interface (not counting the link-local address).
